# Count how many times specific words are used

Tags: r, text-mining

I want to perform textmining on several bank account descriptions. My first step would be get a ranking of the words that are used the most in the description.

So lets say i have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    a                       b
    1 1          House expenses
    2 2 Office furniture bought
    3 3 Office supplies ordered
```

Then I want to create a ranking of the use of the words. Like this:

```
    Name      Times
    1. Office   2
    2. Furniture 1
```

Etc...

Any thoughts on how I can quickly get an overview of the words that are used most in the description?

Comment: Try getting a vector of words with `unlist(strsplit(b, " "))`.  Then you could tabulate with `table`.

Comment: I agree with @Benjamin, but there might be additionally a need to convert the entries into characters if they are stored as factors. Moreover, you mentioned that you wanted a sorted list according to the ranking of the use of words. I think that `sort(table(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$b), " "))), decreasing = T)` should give a result that is very close to your desired output, assuming that `df` is the name of the dataframe.

Comment: ... and if you only want to see, e.g., the five most frequent words, you could wrap this into the `head()` function:
`head(sort(table(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$b)," "))), decreasing = T),5)`

Comment: If you wanted to go further, the tm package and the qdap package both have many more capabilities to analyze text.

Comment: @RHertel thanks, totally worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way around this is using the tm package. 
You can create a corpus:

```
     require(tm)
     corpus <- Corpus(DataframeSource(data))
     dtm<-DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
     dtmDataFrame <- as.data.frame(inspect(dtm))
```

by default it makes term frequencies tf using "weightTf". I converted the Document Term Matrix into a Dataframe. 
 Now what you have is a row per document, a column for each term and the value is the term frequency for every term, you can just create the rankings in a straightforward way, adding all values for each column.

```
colSums(dtmDataFrame)
```

You can sort it too after, whatever. The good point of using tm is that you can filter easily words out, process them with bunch of things like stop words, remove punctuations, stemming, remove sparse words in case you need it.

Answer (score 0):

```
   d<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c("1          House expenses", "2 Office furniture bought", "3 Office supplies ordered"), stringsAsFactors =FALSE)
   e <- unlist(strsplit(d$b, " "))
   f <- e[! e %in% c("")]
   g <- sapply(f, function(x) { sum(f %in% c(x))})
   h = data.frame(Name=names(g), Times=g)
   h[!duplicated(h),]
```